# ask Baby Rudin chapter 3 exercise 6(c)

Tags: analysis

Indicate the behavior (convergence or divergence) of $\Sigma a_n$ if

$$a_n = (\sqrt[n]{n} -1)^n$$

I solve this question by using the first solution. I don't understand the second solution. How to get $a_n \leq 2^{-n}$ for all large n?

[image]

Comment: it is because: if $0<s<t$, then $0<s^k<t^k$ for any integer $k >0$

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sqrt[n]{n}\rightarrow 1$, there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies
$$0<\sqrt[n]{n}-1<\frac{1}{2}\mbox{,}$$
and hence
$$a_n<2^{-n}\mbox{.}$$